# Loop through simple xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a soap message

```
 <soapenv:Envelope 
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
         <id>0</id>
         <id>1</id>
       </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to loop through the id elements and check if the current one has a value = 1 but my xslt is not working.

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select="node()">
          <xsl:if test="current()/text='1'">
          do something
          </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
```

Can someone point out what I do wrong and give me directions on how to proceed?

**EDIT: I need something that will return   true when one of  id's is equal to 1, otherwise false .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to loop through the id elements and check if the current one
>   has a value = 1

You don't need to do that. The following expression:

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/id=1
```

will return `true` if one or more of the `id` elements has the value of 1, `false` otherwise.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGc8

Comment: @banb It's not a workaround. That's how [comparisons](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) work in XPath (as well as most languages that deal with sets).

Comment: wrong use of words but thank you, I will read upon that. Sorry to ask but can you show me a way to return true if all the id's are equal to 1?

Comment: I think I have just answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157336/3016153

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope">
        <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body">
            <xsl:if test="id='1'">
                do something
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
You may use like this
```

Comment: Thank you @imran. That was very  helpful but can you see my post's edit and help me?