# XSLT to return boolean value if all tags are equal to value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <success>0</success>
    <success>0</success>
    <success>1</success>
</soapenv:Body>
```

And I want to implement logic that will return true if one of the success tags is equal to 0 and false if all of them are equal to 0.

So far I have but I don't know how to make the xslt to retun errorFlag=false if all of them are =0:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="test" />
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body" name ="test">
   <errorFlag>
     <xsl:if test="contains(.,'0')">true</xsl:if>
   </errorFlag>
</xsl:template>
```

Wanted output -only one field:

```
<errorFlag>true<errorFlag> (if all are success=0)
```

Comment: what you want output

Comment: edited the post

Comment: What result would you want if there were only a single `<success>0</success>`? "true" because there is one element equal to 0 or "false" because "all" (the single one) have the value 0?

Comment: **Note**: when you call a template by name, its `match` attribute is ignored. Your `.` selects the entire document, because you're still in the context of `/``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="succKey" match="success" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="test" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body" name="test">
    <xsl:variable name="key-count"
        select="count(//success[generate-id() =
                               generate-id(key('succKey', .))])" />
    <errorFlag>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$key-count = 1">
                <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </errorFlag>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh33

Comment: You can change true/ false value in `xsl:text` based on your condition as your two sentences contradicts in question on when it should be true and when it should be false. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this answer is wrong. It will return `true` when all `success` element are equal to 0 OR when all `success` element are equal to 1: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh33/1 (not to mention how unnecessary convoluted it is).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: It has been already explained in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <errorFlag>
         <xsl:value-of select="not(/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/success=1)" />
    </errorFlag>
</xsl:template>
```

Or (requires XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <errorFlag>
        <xsl:value-of select="every $item in /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/success satisfies $item=0"/>
    </errorFlag>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The answer is good but I'm using WSO2 to build my service which uses this XSLT but somehow when it transforms the message with it it returns true when all are equal to 1.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce your problem: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifph

Answer (score 1):

> I want to implement logic that will return true if one of the success
>   tags is equal to 0 and false if all of them are equal to 0.

First, let's make the truth table:

```
All zeros | None zero | Some zero, others not
-------------------------------------------
  False   |   False   |        True
```

Second, [node-set comparison](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) in XPath are existencial. So:

```
boolean(/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body[success = 0 and success != 0])
```

It will return `true` or `false` boolean value.

This input

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <success>0</success>
    <success>0</success>
    <success>1</success>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of 
         select="boolean(
                    /soapenv:Envelope
                       /soapenv:Body[
                          success = 0 and success != 0
                       ]
                 )"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns

```
true
```

Check it in http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=ceed7a50-6a47-4c2c-b344-86ad3b3b0d92-xsltransformation