# How to create a boolean variable for if-conditions in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I want to iterate a list node to check if every node field matches a global value.
The result should be written into a boolean variable. And only if that is `true` (thus all "Segments" are valid), I want to continue with my logic.

```
<!-- TODO how to set mytest=true by default? -->
<xsl:variable name="mytest">
    <xsl:for-each select="Segment">
            <xsl:if test=".//SegmentField != $globalValue">
                    <!-- TODO how to set mytest = false? -->
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$mytest">
    <xsl:for-each select="Segment">
        ...creating a csv string
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Or as an alternative, I could check if `$mytest` is either `true` or undefined, like (pseudocode):

```
<xsl:if test="$mytest || not($mytest)">
```

But how? My goal is to simply check that all `SegmentField` values inside each `Segment` are equal.

Example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6i/1

```
<OuterElement>
    <SegmentWrapper>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>A</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>A</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
    </SegmentWrapper>
    <SegmentWrapper>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>B</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>B</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
    </SegmentWrapper>
    <SegmentWrapper>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>A</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
        <Segment>
            <SegmentField>B</SegmentField>
        </Segment>
    </SegmentWrapper>
</OuterElement>
```

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="OuterElement">
    <xsl:for-each select="SegmentWrapper//Segment">
        <xsl:variable name="mytest" select="not(Segment[SegmentField != SegmentField[1]])" />

        <xsl:if test="$mytest">
            <xsl:value-of select=".//SegmentField" separator=";"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

This should print

```
A;A
B;B
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157336/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should be able to simplify it to just this...

```
<xsl:variable name="mytest" select="not(Segment[SegmentField != $globalValue])" />
```

So, the expression `Segment[SegmentField != $globalValue])` returns all `Segments` where the `SegmentField` does not match the global value. By applying `not` on this, if there are any elements in the set, then using `not` will return false, otherwise it returns false.

EDIT: In answer to your edit, if you wanted to check all SegmentField values were the same per SegmentWrapper, you would define your variable like so

```
<xsl:variable name="mytest" select="not(Segment/SegmentField != Segment/SegmentField)" />
```

This may seem odd at first glance, as you might think `Segment/SegmentField != Segment/SegmentField` will always be false. But `Segment/SegmentField` returns a sequence, and when you a comparison operator on this, it will return true if one of the nodes in the first sequence compares with one in the second sequence.

You don't really need the variable though, you could write this:

```
<xsl:template match="OuterElement">
  <xsl:for-each select="SegmentWrapper[not(Segment/SegmentField != Segment/SegmentField)]">
    <xsl:value-of select=".//SegmentField" separator=";"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work. I added an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Please have a look at my xsltfiddle.

Comment: I could probably drop $globalValue and make direct reference to `SegmentField[1]`, but how? At least `not(Segment[SegmentField != SegmentField[1]])` does not work...

Comment: @membersound You are missing the point: there's no need for `xsl:for each`. See: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6i/2

Comment: Ty so much for your example, I could get it working with it!

Comment: Regarding your edit: as I need to define the `$globalValue` anyways and reuse it at another stage, could I as well compare with it like: `select="not(Segment/SegmentField != $globalValue)" />`? It worked in my test, though I'm not sure if it is valid to compare a sequence with a fixed value?

Comment: When you test a sequence against a fixed value, it will check all nodes in the sequence against that fixed value, and return true if just one of those nodes has a match (i.e doing `Segment/SegmentField != $globalValue` will return true if just one SegmentField is not equal to the globalValue.